'stats' not allowed in Vue 3 cli?
I am trying to generate a stats report for my Vue 3 project. There is no way I can enable stats. I currently use webpack-bundle-analyzer to view a map of the bundles, but enabling a report for it throws a stats error. Tried using webpack-stats-report as well. Even the vue cli '--report' param throws an error for stats.

Does anyone know how to generate a report in Vue cli?

What version of the CLI are you running?

@micahlt 4.5.19

Could you share your vue.config.js file ?
